# flatten list of numpy arrays while keeping inner arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy

```
l = [np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]), np.array([5,6]), np.array([[7,8],[9,10],[11,12]])]
```

I'm trying to flatten this list of arrays but keeping the inner arrays:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
```

I tried `itertools.chain`, `np.concatenate`, `np.flatten` but none of these options give the output above

Comment: `np.vstack(l)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your arrays have different numbers of dimensions, you need to ensure they all are 2D:

```
out = np.concatenate([x[None,:] if x.ndim == 1 else x for x in l])
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12]])
```

or with `itertools.chain` with a list output:

```
from itertools import chain
list(chain.from_iterable([x.tolist()] if x.ndim == 1 else x.tolist()
                         for x in l))
```

output: `[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]`

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided your desired output. But, as I understood, you are looking for this:

```
x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10], [11, 12]]
print([n for m in x for n in m])
```

with output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Please let me know if this is not your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to flatten each subarray, concatenate them and finally reshape it.

```
np.concatenate(list(map(np.ravel, l))).reshape(-1, 2)
```

output:

```
array([[ 1,  2],
       [ 3,  4],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 7,  8],
       [ 9, 10],
       [11, 12]])
```